# Ionic 4 Lottie Animation issue

Tags: ionic4

I simply install lottie plugin im using it in app.component.ts to show the screen but its showing error

```
TypeError: this.lottieSplashScreen.show(...).then is not a function
```

can any one please tell the issue i need to show it like splash screen thanks.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { LottieSplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/lottie-splash-screen/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  public appPages = [
    {
      title: 'Home',
      url: '/home',
      icon: 'home'
    },
    {
      title: 'List',
      url: '/list',
      icon: 'list'
    }
  ];

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private lottieSplashScreen: LottieSplashScreen
  ) {

    this.initializeApp();

  this.lottieSplashScreen.show('https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_CLhLRL/data.json', false, 1024, 768)
  .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ionic native always should be in device ready :

```
import { LottieSplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/lottie-splash-screen/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

class ...
constructor(public plt: Platform, private lottieSplashScreen: LottieSplashScreen){
plt.ready().then(()=>{
   this.lottieSplashScreen.show('https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_CLhLRL/data.json', false, 1024, 768)
  .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . Its showing error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'. now.

Comment: have you installed plugin properly ? check that